# How can I install specific python library in virtual environment in Dockerfile(airflow)?

Tags: docker, airflow, virtualenv

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.4.3-python3.8
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         vim \
         gcc \
         g++ \
         libsasl2-dev \
         libc6-dev \
         git \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

USER airflow
RUN python -m virtualenv dbt_venv && source dbt_venv/bin/activate && \
  pip install dbt-core
```

When I built an image based on this, it raised error:
`ERROR: Can not perform a '--user' install. User site-packages are not visible in this virtualenv.`

I think this is kinda `USER` problem but have no idea how to handle this.

I don't need persistence of virtualenv, which mean it doesn't have to be activated whenever container run. I'd like to just install some packges in virtualenv.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [apache/airflow Dockerfile](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1290a17013f9c43434eec207cf06c1c7c6ce5942/Dockerfile#L1402) sets env var `PIP_USER=true`. Toggle it it to work with virtualenvs:

```
ENV PIP_USER=false
```

before your last `RUN`.

Another approach is to clear it right in the `RUN`:

```
RUN python -m virtualenv dbt_venv && source dbt_venv/bin/activate && \
  PIP_USER=false pip install dbt-core
```